# Azure AD OpenId Connect Token Authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, openid, dotnetopenauth

I am stuck with Azure Active Directory OpenId.
I Have a **ReactJs Web Client** that does Authentication to Azure AD, When signed in a `token_id` is return representing a JWT token.
 This will be passed back to a ASP.Net Core Web Api and then Authenticated with the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` in `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`.

This is wired up with the Middelware when the application starts. When you access the OpenIdConnectOption Events on TokenValidated call, the token is validated already in the back end. A TokenValidatedContext get passed in to the Event Method which contains the JwtSecurityToken and I have access to the whole JWT Token.

I created a separate validation service that takes in the token string.

```
 public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        var sectoken = TokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);

        var tokenValidationParams = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
         ValidAudiences = sectoken.Audiences,
         ValidIssuer = sectoken.Issuer,

        };

        return TokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParams, out validatedToken);
    }
```

Is that the SigningKey object is null and the ValidateToken fails. If I do the same validation in the Event call then the SigningKey is valid and the cert is set to Microsoft Cert that seems to be issues by the Azure AD Service.

The main objective is to have a separate Token Validation Service.

Thanks in advance.